# How to prevent ADMX template Group Policy from removing registry values when policy is removed or disabled?

Tags: group-policy

I am using an ADMX Template to set a registry values. The key for the values  already exists on the machines, and it may be changed but not removed or it will impact the service which depends on it.

The problem is that if I set policy to "Disabled" in gpedit.msc it actually deletes every value mentioned in template.

Lets say I have a registry key:

**Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TestPolicy**

There are already two string values:

- **PreExistingValueChanged** = "SomeValue"
- PreExistingValueUnchanged = "SomeValue"

Now, my template when enabled sets up:

- PolicyEnabled = "1"
- **PreExistingValueChanged** = "NewValue"

However, if I disable template, I end up with only PreExistingValueUnchanged and PolicyEnabled = "0" remaining (so **PreExistingValueChanged** is gone).

How can I change template for PreExistingValueChanged to stay when template is disabled?

**TestPolicy.admx:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  (c) 2006 Microsoft Corporation  -->
<policyDefinitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" revision="1.0" schemaVersion="1.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/2006/07/PolicyDefinitions">
  <policyNamespaces>
    <target prefix="testpolicy" namespace="Microsoft.Policies.TestPolicy" />
    <using prefix="windows" namespace="Microsoft.Policies.Windows" />
  </policyNamespaces>
  <resources minRequiredRevision="1.0" />
  <categories>
    <category name="TestPolicy" displayName="$(string.TestPolicy)">
      <parentCategory ref="windows:WindowsComponents" />
    </category>
  </categories>
  <policies>
    <policy name="TestPolicyString" class="Machine" displayName="$(string.TestPolicyString)" explainText="$(string.TestPolicyString_help)" presentation="$(presentation.TestPolicyPresentation)" key="SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TestPolicy" valueName="PolicyEnabled">
      <parentCategory ref="TestPolicy" />
      <supportedOn ref="windows:SUPPORTED_WindowsVista" />
      <enabledValue>
        <decimal value="1" />
      </enabledValue>
      <disabledValue>
        <decimal value="0" />
      </disabledValue>
      <elements>
        <enum id="TestPolicyPresentation_Levels" valueName="PreExistingValueChanged" required="true">
          <item displayName="$(string.TestPolicyOption_1)">
            <value>
              <string>Option 1</string>
            </value>
          </item>
          <item displayName="$(string.TestPolicyOption_2)">
            <value>
              <string>Option 2</string>
            </value>
          </item>
        </enum>
      </elements>
    </policy>
  </policies>
</policyDefinitions>
```

**TestPolicy.adml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  (c) 2006 Microsoft Corporation  -->
<policyDefinitionResources xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" revision="1.0" schemaVersion="1.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/2006/07/PolicyDefinitions">
  <displayName>Test ADMX Template</displayName>
  <description>Sets up specific value to registry</description>
  <resources>
    <stringTable>
      <string id="TestPolicy">Test Policy</string>
      <string id="TestPolicyString">Configure machine's registry key</string>
      <string id="TestPolicyString_help">This policy sets specific reg value</string>
      <string id="TestPolicyOption_1">Changable Value Opt 1</string>
      <string id="TestPolicyOption_2">Changable Value Opt 2</string>
    </stringTable>
    <presentationTable>
      <presentation id="TestPolicyPresentation">
        <dropdownList refId="TestPolicyPresentation_Levels" noSort="true" defaultItem="0">Specify option</dropdownList>
      </presentation>
    </presentationTable>
  </resources>
</policyDefinitionResources>
```

Policy is under **Computer Configuration  - Administrative Templates - Windows Components - Test Policy**

Comment: Templates are not the right approach. You need to use Group Policy Preferences.